# Apps install data in phone storage instead of sd card

Tags: sd-card, google-play-games

This is really annoying me. I had deleted a 1GB game to free up space and install a game but I set all download and install locations to sd card but the app store downloads the game to the phone storage and the game spreads out it's data in there aswell! Why does it not install on sd card when I set it so?

Answer (score 2):

sometimes the games app are configured in a way that they store their data in the phone storage for security or for getting smooth performance. there is nothing you can do about it.....it is more of an developer choice of storage location.

Comment: You're wrong. I had the game before installed on sd card and no significant update has happened to modify that.

Comment: the same game you are talking about

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the same game!